# Regex: replace backslash with double-backslash, but not double-backslash with quadruple-backslash

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
s/\\/\\\\/g
```

This does a nice job of replacing all "`\`" characters with "`\\`".  However, I want to guard against matching backslashes that are adjacent to other backslashes.  If I do this:

```
s/[^\\]\\[^\\]/\\\\/g
```

it only catches non-adjacent backslashes.  But now there's the obvious problem that the matches include the two neighboring charaters that shouldn't be replaced.  How can I overcome this?

Comment: you need to do some kind of unless usually with a lookahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a negative lookahead to specify "replace this slash unless it is followed by another slash"?

Comment: Thanks, as a regex beginner I just needed to hear the term "lookahead". I have what I need now.

Comment: What's the answer to this question?

Comment: Almost a useful answer, but is actually just a question

Answer (score 1):

With negative lookahead and negative lookbehind, this seems to work:

```
"(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)"
```

In PowerShell, this is the result:

```
"foo\\Bar foo\bar" -replace "(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)","\\"
foo\\Bar foo\\bar
```

It also results in `foo\\\bar` not being affected - that may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what escaped characters you want to match you can always just include all those cases (\n,\r,\t,\"....)

Answer (score 0):

s/([^\\])\\([^\\])/$1\\\\$2/g

Comment: Does this miss a beginning of line backslash?  End of line (not that that would likely be a concern)?

Comment: Yes. It also misses backslashes separated by a single char. But it matches the question :)